# Checking Code For Potential Java 7/8 Improvements

Tags: java, standards

Can anyone recommend any tools that can check my code and recommend places I could use the latest Java improvements.  For example, it would be nice if I had a tool that could see something like:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Spot that I am using Java 1.7 & recommend that I can ditch the second `<String>` in favour of `<>`.  Another example could be multi catch blocks.

I'm so used to using the Java 1.6 & below syntax, that I'm often forgetting I could use these little space saving tricks. The only way I'm going to start remembering to use them if something points out when I'm not.

I've not spotted anything in Eclipse (my IDE of choice), PMD or CheckStyle.  I realise I can write my own checks in things like Checkstyle but surely this must have been done already?

Comment: If you look under Preferences --> Java --> Compiler --> Errors/Warnings there are a few things that you can turn on that warn you about features that later Java versions have. There aren't nearly enough warnings to catch everything new though, but it's something...

Answer (score 2):

I use IntelliJ CE for this.  It has auto-fixes for the migration tools.  The free version has about 600 checks, the paid for version has checks/refactoring for libraries like Spring etc.

You can do a global search and fix for `<>` operators.
Note: you cannot use `<>`for anonymous sub-classes.

[image]

It also has an auto-fix for

```
    try {

    } catch(NullPointerException npe) {
        npe.printStackTrace();
    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
        nfe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It will merge identical branches.

It will also refactor the following to use ARM.

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("myfile");
    try {

    } finally {
        fis.close();
    }
```

Comment: @downvoter Care to say why?

Comment: If the OP only wants eclipse plugins, I can delete this answer.

Comment: Although I mentioned I use Eclipse, I didn't say I specifically wanted an Eclipse solution. So this is all useful info & not worthy of a downvote.

Comment: The question is about tools in general, so your answer is absolutely correct. Personally, I am using the Ultimate edition and it works perfect for this kind of stuff.

Comment: @LeeTheobald People are too fast with down voting, even if answer is correct.

Comment: @JakubPolák Sometimes people down vote because either a) they don't like the answer, b) don't understand the answer.  In any case, a comment on how to improve is far more useful.  Just because I think I am right doesn't mean a) everyone agrees with me, b) everyone understand what I am going on about, c) couldn't be clearer or add some detail.